# Adding FB share button to pages behind sign-in

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have web page which needs users to sign-in (not FB signin though), and need to add share button to it. Issue is when I share that page, it only posts link to the wall. og image and og:description tags are ignored.

btw i am using iframe to show fb:like

Can you please let me know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate open graph tags even when user is not logged in.